# Microsoft Graph API - Upload large file - Azure AD App with Sites.selected permission

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have registered an application on our Azure AD, and granted it the Sites.Selected permission as well as granting it access to a specific Sharepoint site following this guide. (Sites.ReadWrite.All is not an option as it would give access to all sites)

https://ashiqf.com/2021/03/15/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-sharepoint-sites-selected-application-permission-in-a-azure-ad-application-for-more-granular-control/

Now I am trying to use Postman to send web requests to the Microsoft Graph API in order to upload large files so I want to use the createUploadSession endpoint.
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/drive/items/{{Item_id}}:/test.rtf:/createUploadSession](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7Bsite_id%7D%7D/drive/items/%7B%7BItem_id%7D%7D:/test.rtf:/createUploadSession)

But I get the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "notAllowed",
        "message": "Operation not allowed",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-02-04T14:04:37",
            "request-id": "06e86b5b-6067-4d7b-9ce9-af41de95406f",
            "client-request-id": "06e86b5b-6067-4d7b-9ce9-af41de95406f"
        }
    }
}
```

I know the authentication token I use is valid because a request to directly upload a file works fine and uploads the file.
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/drive/items/{{Item_id}}:/test.rtf:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7Bsite_id%7D%7D/drive/items/%7B%7BItem_id%7D%7D:/test.rtf:/content)

Any ideas for what could be wrong with my request to start an upload session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that `item_id` is id of the destination folder but I'm not sure whether you can upload large this way

```
v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/drive/items/{{Item_id}}:/test.rtf:/createUploadSession
```

Try to specify the path to the file from the root

```
POST v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/drive/items/root:/test.rtf:/createUploadSession
```

Also check whether the `POST` HTTP method is set.

Comment: Yes Item id is for the destination folder. Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately with that request i get the error "Invalid request"

I think removing one ":" would make a valid request v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/drive/items/root:/test.rtf:/createUploadSession but then i get the same error as before "Operation not allowed"

Comment: @Björn Do you use POST http method?

Comment: I can't believe I missed the POST. Copied the postman request from the working one with a different AD app but the Method must have been lost. Thank you that was the error.